# A que se debe que mi variable pnombre me salga como NULL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, cursor, mysql-cursores, mysql-cursores-anidados

## Mi base de datos :

```
# BORRAR BASES DE DATOS COCINA SI EXISTE
    
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS COCINA;
    
    # CREAR BASES DE DATOS COCINA SI NO EXISTE
    
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS COCINA;
    
    # USAR BASES DE DATOS DE COCINA
    
    USE COCINA;
    
    # CREAR TABLA PLATOS
    
    CREATE TABLE PLATOS(
        CODIGO INT(4) PRIMARY KEY,
        DIFICULTA VARCHAR(10),
        MENU_DIA BOOLEAN,
        NOMBRE VARCHAR(45),
        PRECIO FLOAT(5),
        RECETAS TEXT
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE PLATOS
    
    INSERT INTO PLATOS VALUES(1,'PINCHE',TRUE,'SOPA DE ALETA DE TIBURON',6.00,'Antes de comenzar a elaborar esta receta, debemos poner en remojo la aleta de tiburón, durante
    2 días, y las setas chinas, durante 1 día. Pasado ese tiempo, las limpiamos, las secamos y las
    troceamos.
    Ponemos a calentar el caldo. Cortamos la pechuga de pollo en tiras finas y la incorporamos al
    caldo, junto con el resto de ingredientes, menos la harina y las almendras. Dejamos cocer, a
    fuego lento, durante 1 hora.
    Pasado ese tiempo, diluimos la harina de maíz en un poco de agua fría y la añadimos a la sopa
    para que espese. Ponemos también almendras al gusto. Rectificamos de sal y servimos.
    Para hacer la sopa más consistente podemos añadir al final una clara de huevo batida.
    La sopa de aleta de tiburón es más valorada por su textura que por su valor nutritivo, que es
    escaso. Podemos destacar el aporte de proteínas que suma la carne y el caldo de pollo, pero
    posee menos vitaminas y minerales que una tradicional sopa de verduras, por ejemplo.
    El alto contenido en mercurio de la aleta de tiburón hace que este plato no esté indicado para
    mujeres embarazadas y niños.'),
                             (10,'COCINERO',FALSE,'CREMA DE HIGOS AL OPORTO',7.00,NULL),
                             (11,'CHEF',FALSE,'CORDERO LECHAL CON ESPECIAS AROMAT',14.00,'Lo primero que haremos será empezar con el aderezo del cordero. La noche antes de asar el
    cordero preparamos un majado de tomillo fresco, romero fresco, ajo y aceite hasta la mitad del
    mortero.
    Impregnamos el cordero con la mezcla anterior, lo tapamos con film y lo guardamos en la nevera
    hasta el día siguiente.
    Precalentamos el horno a una temperatura alta, unos 250o C, para que al meter el cordero no
    tenga que cocinarse partiendo de un entorno frío.
    Cuando lo vayamos a asar, sacamos el cordero y salamos bien la carne por ambos lados.
    Colocamos la pierna en una cazuela de barro o cerámica, con la parte interior hacia arriba.
    Aunque os sobresalga un poco no os preocupéis ya que durante el horneado menguará de
    tamaño.
    Si no disponéis de este recipiente cabría la posibilidad de cocinarlo sobre la bandeja metálica del
    horno, aunque en este caso te recomiendo poner un poco de manteca en el agua. De este modo
    se evaporará más lentamente y no tendremos que reponerla.
    Bajamos la temperatura del horno a 160o C, necesitamos el horno con temperatura arriba y abajo.
    Vertemos el vaso de agua y el de vino blanco en la base de la cazuela o en la bandeja del horno
    y metemos todo en el horno.'),
                             (2,'COCINERO',FALSE,'POLLO CON SALSA DE ALMENDRAS',7.00,NULL),
                             (3,'COCINERO',FALSE,'PROFITEROLES CON CHOCOLATE',3.00,'En primer lugar precalentar el horno a 180 grados y preparar una bandeja de horno con papel
    pergamino o vegetal.
    Por otro lado, tamizamos la harina con ayuda de un colador o un tamizador. Por otro lado, en un
    cazo ponemos la mantequilla junto a la sal y 87 ml de agua, remover. Añadir la harina y formar
    una bola retirándola a un lado del cazo. A continuación, añadir los huevos uno a uno y batir hasta
    lograr una masa homogénea.
    En una manga pastelera o una bolsa de congelar tipo Zip, añadimos la masa y cortamos uno de
    los extremos. Hacemos 18 pastelitos del tamaño aproximado de una nuez. Hornear a 180 grados
    durante 35 minutos o hasta que los notes ligeramente dorados. Los dejamos enfriar.
    Preparando el ganache de chocolate
    
    Como buscamos un ganache suave para relleno la proporción es una parte de chocolate por dos
    de nata. Para coberturas donde buscamos una textua más firma sería proporción 1:1.
    Comenzamos troceandor el chocolate para picarlo podemos introducirlo en la picadora o poner
    trocitos en el mortero y darle ligeros golpecitos. Poner el chocolate en el microondas junto a una
    cucharadita de leche 30 segundos a máxima potencia. Trascurrido este tiempo si aún no está
    fundido del todo le damos 20 segundos a plena potencia y dejamos reposar un minuto. Luego
    vertemos ya el chocolate fundido donde tengamos la nata montada y mezclamos.
    En otra bolsa tipo Zip añadimos todo el ganache de chocolate, apretamos y hacemos un corte
    en el extremo. Cortar por la mitad los profiteroles y rellenarlos con el ganache. En la parte
    superior puedes añadir un poco más de ganache de chocolate azúcar glas o fideos de chocolate.'),
                             (4,'COCINERO',FALSE,'CREPES CON ROQUEFORT',4.00,NULL),
                             (5,'CHEF',FALSE,'POLLO TANDOHORI',12.00,NULL),
                             (6,'CHEF',FALSE,'PECHUGA DE PATO A SALSA GROSELLAS',15.00,NULL),
                             (7,'COCINERO',TRUE,'ESCALOPE DE TERNERA',7.50,NULL),
                             (8,'PINCHE',TRUE,'BOQUERONES EN VINAGRE',6.00,'Lo más importante en esta receta es la calidad de la materia prima que utilicéis. Los boquerones
    deben estar frescos. Boquerones tiesos, que ofrezca un poco de resistencia al doblarlo.
    La piel tiene que estar muy brillante y los ojos bien transparentes. Yo me suelo fiar al 100% de
    mi pescadera Isa, además es muy maja y me suele preguntar cómo los quiero y que receta voy
    a preparar con ellos.
    La parte de la limpieza es el trabajo más laborioso. Si no tenéis un pescadero/a majo debéis
    limpiarlos en casa, lo mejor es hacerlo en el fregadero debajo de un chorro de agua muy fría.
    De uno en uno, rompiendo la cabeza y arrastrando con la uña del pulgar las tripas y la espina,
    todo a la vez.
    Al hacer esto el boquerón queda abierto por la mitad, los dos lomos juntos en la cola, quitad
    separadlos y quitar la cola para que queden dos lomos separados y limpios.
    Lavamos los boquerones (tanto si ya vienen del pescadero limpios como si has hecho el trabajo
    en casa). Tienen que quedan bien limpios, sin restos de sangre.
    Ponemos encima de papel absorbente y secamos bien presionando por encima con más papel.
    Así lo tendremos listos para el marinado. Reservamos.
    El proceso de limpieza y el congelado posterior es fundamental para un buen resultado final.'),
                             (9,'COCINERO',TRUE,'AJO BLANCO CON UVA MOSCATEL',5.00,NULL);
    
    # CREAR TABLA COMPOSICION
    
    CREATE TABLE COMPOSICION(
        COD_PLATO INT(3),
        NOMBRE VARCHAR(30),
        CANTIDAD INT(4),
        PRIMARY KEY(COD_PLATO,NOMBRE)
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE COMPOSICION
    
    INSERT INTO COMPOSICION VALUES(1,'ALETA DE TIBURON',150),
                                  (1,'ALMENDRAS',30),
                                  (10,'HIGOS',100),
                                  (10,'OPORTO',25),
                                  (11,'ACEITE DE OLIVA',20),
                                  (11,'CLAVO',2),
                                  (11,'CORDERO',150),
                                  (11,'ROMERO',2),
                                  (2,'ALMENDRAS',30),
                                  (2,'POLLO',200),
                                  (3,'ALMENDRAS',15),
                                  (3,'BARRAS DE CHOCOLATE FONDANT',50),
                                  (3,'PROFITEROLES',100),
                                  (4,'CREPES',200),
                                  (4,'QUESO ROQUEFORT',100),
                                  (5,'CARDAMOMO',2),
                                  (5,'CURCUMA',2),
                                  (5,'POLLO',200),
                                  (6,'GROSELLA',20),
                                  (6,'PATO',100),
                                  (6,'VINAGRE',15),
                                  (7,'CLAVO',15),
                                  (7,'SOLOMILLO DE TERNERA',150),
                                  (8,'BOQUERONES',100),
                                  (8,'VINAGRE',15),
                                  (9,'ACEITE DE OLIVA',15),
                                  (9,'ALMENDRAS',120),
                                  (9,'UVA MOSCATEL',30);
    
    # CREAR TABLA PROVEEDORES
    
    CREATE TABLE PROVEEDORES(
        NIF VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
        NOMBRE VARCHAR(25),
        DIRECCION VARCHAR(35)
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE PROVEEDORES
    
    INSERT INTO PROVEEDORES VALUES('00188327R','KEMPO ICHI','DOMICILIOC/ALPARGATERITO, 2'),
                                  ('22777364G','TRANS PEPE','PZA. CONSTITUCION, 5'),
                                  ('23877346B','PRODUCTOS GALLO','AVD. BARCELONA, 23'),
                                  ('33562837H','AVICOLA','C/ FLAUTISTA DE HAMELIN, 3'),
                                  ('36636773G','GEMASA','BVD. LUIS PASTEUR, S/N'),
                                  ('78365636J','SALAZAR','C/ CARNICERITO, 56'),
                                  ('78373673T','FRUTAS ORTIZ','C/ ALFA, 45'),
                                  ('82664939H','BEBIDAS Y REFRESCOS PEPÍN','AVD. DR. ESCASSI, 15'),
                                  ('89623663T','SURFOTMAN','C/ NABUCO, S/N'),
                                  ('98236777M','PEDRO GÓMEZ','C/ CUARTELES, 12'),
                                  ('98623629C','AVIMA','C/ JACINTO VERDAGUER, 12'),
                                  ('99387467M','TINTORROS DE TRABUCO','PZA. GOYA, 12');
    
    # CREAR TABLA SUMINISTROS
    
    CREATE TABLE SUMINISTROS(
        NIF_PROVEEDOR VARCHAR(9),
        NOMBRE_ALIMENTO VARCHAR(35),
        PRIMARY KEY (NIF_PROVEEDOR,NOMBRE_ALIMENTO)
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE SUMINISTROS
    
    INSERT INTO SUMINISTROS VALUES('00188327R','ACEITE DE OLIVA'),
                                  ('00188327R','PATO'),
                                  ('22777364G','ALETA DE TIBURON'),
                                  ('22777364G','POLLO'),
                                  ('23877346B','ACEITE DE OLIVA'),
                                  ('23877346B','ALMENDRAS'),
                                  ('23877346B','BOQUERONES'),
                                  ('23877346B','PROFITEROLES'),
                                  ('33562837H','BARRAS DE CHOCOLATE FONDANT'),
                                  ('33562837H','CORDERO'),
                                  ('33562837H','QUESO ROQUEFORT'),
                                  ('36636773G','BOQUERONES'),
                                  ('36636773G','PATO'),
                                  ('36636773G','ROMERO'),
                                  ('78365636J','CARDAMOMO'),
                                  ('78365636J','SOLOMILLO DE TERNERA'),
                                  ('78373673T','CLAVO'),
                                  ('78373673T','GROSELLA'),
                                  ('78373673T','UVA MOSCATEL'),
                                  ('82664939H','CREPES'),
                                  ('89623663T','CORDERO'),
                                  ('89623663T','VINAGRE'),
                                  ('98236777M','CURCUMA'),
                                  ('98236777M','PATO'),
                                  ('98236777M','QUESO ROQUEFORT'),
                                  ('98236777M','VINAGRE'),
                                  ('98623629C','CURCUMA'),
                                  ('98623629C','HIGOS'),
                                  ('99387467M','OPORTO');
    
    # CREAR TABLA FACTURAS
    
    CREATE TABLE FACTURAS(
        NUMERO INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
        SUBTOTAL FLOAT(6),
        DESCUENTO FLOAT(5),
        IVA FLOAT(5),
        TOTAL FLOAT(6),
        PENDIENTE_PAGO BOOLEAN,
        NIF_PROVEEDOR VARCHAR(9),
        FECHA DATE
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE FACTURAS
    
    INSERT INTO FACTURAS VALUES(1,250.00,25.00,40.50,265.50,FALSE,'00188327R','2008-06-12'),
                               (2,350.00,50.00,54.00,354.00,FALSE,'00188327R','2009-07-13'),
                               (3,200.00,15.00,51.30,336.30,FALSE,'00188327R','2010-12-21'),
                               (4,500.00,60.00,79.20,519.20,TRUE,'00188327R','2011-03-01'),
                               (5,600.00,75.00,94.50,619.50,FALSE,'22777364G','2009-08-23'),
                               (6,400.00,20.00,68.40,448.40,TRUE,'22777364G','2010-12-12'),
                               (7,650.00,50.00,94.50,694.50,FALSE,'23877346B','2008-08-21'),
                               (8,700.00,80.00,111.60,731.60,FALSE,'23877346B','2009-09-16'),
                               (9,500.00,30.00,84.60,554.60,TRUE,'23877346B','2010-12-30'),
                               (10,670.00,70.00,94.50,619.50,FALSE,'33562837H','2009-12-30'),
                               (11,400.00,20.00,68.40,448.40,FALSE,'33562837H','2010-12-21'),
                               (12,800.00,100.00,126.00,826.00,TRUE,'33562837H','2011-02-12'),
                               (13,500.00,60.00,79.20,519.20,FALSE,'36636773G','2011-02-21'),
                               (14,820.00,20.00,144.00,944.00,FALSE,'78365636J','2010-09-18'),
                               (15,430.00,15.00,74.70,489.70,TRUE,'78365636J','2011-01-10'),
                               (16,690.00,90.00,94.50,694.50,FALSE,'78373673T','2008-07-16'),
                               (17,1020.00,70.00,171.00,1121.00,FALSE,'78373673T','2009-10-07'),
                               (18,980.00,40.00,169.20,1109.20,TRUE,'78373673T','2010-12-19'),
                               (19,700.00,80.00,111.60,731.60,FALSE,'82664939H','2010-12-12'),
                               (20,200.00,15.00,51.30,336.30,FALSE,'89623663T','2010-11-19'),
                               (21,400.00,20.00,68.40,448.40,FALSE,'89623663T','2011-02-27'),
                               (22,675.00,50.00,112.50,737.50,FALSE,'98236777M','2008-12-30'),
                               (23,1009.00,45.00,173.52,1137.52,FALSE,'98236777M','2009-12-30'),
                               (24,1500.00,200.00,234.00,1534.00,FALSE,'98236777M','2010-12-30'),
                               (25,1650.00,150.00,252.00,1750.00,TRUE,'98236777M','2011-01-03'),
                               (26,1650.00,150.00,252.00,1750.00,TRUE,'98236777M','2011-03-03'),
                               (27,250.00,25.00,40.50,265.50,FALSE,'98623629C','2010-11-22'),
                               (28,800.00,100.00,126.00,826.00,FALSE,'98623629C','2010-12-12'),
                               (29,700.00,80.00,111.60,731.60,FALSE,'99387467M','2010-12-30'),
                               (30,500.00,60.00,79.20,519.20,TRUE,'99387467M','2011-02-19');
```

**Resulta que debo realizar un triple cursor el cual el enunciado es el siguiente :** Usando 3 cursores anidados, mostrar para cada plato sus componentes, y para cada uno de ellos los nombres de sus posibles proveedores.

Me muestra correctamente los platos con sus componentes pero los proveedores no me muestra nada y me debe poner el proveedor o proveedores que que suministra ese o esos alimentos .

**Nota :** PNOMBRE es el nombre de los proveedores y es obligatorio si o si usar un triple cursor de lo contrario este ejercicio estaría mal.

## Mi tripleCursor.sql

```
USE COCINA;

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS plato $$
CREATE PROCEDURE plato()
BEGIN
     DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
     DECLARE c_platos VARCHAR(45);
     DECLARE c_codPla INT;
     DECLARE c_nombres VARCHAR(30);
     DECLARE c_nif VARCHAR(9);
     DECLARE c_pnombres VARCHAR(45);
     DECLARE cur_platos CURSOR FOR SELECT codigo,NOMBRE FROM PLATOS;
     DECLARE cur_componentes CURSOR FOR SELECT COMPOSICION.NOMBRE 
     FROM COMPOSICION,PLATOS where COMPOSICION.COD_PLATO=PLATOS.codigo 
     AND COMPOSICION.COD_PLATO=c_codPla;
     DECLARE cur_proveedores CURSOR FOR SELECT PROVEEDORES.nif,PROVEEDORES.nombre 
     FROM PROVEEDORES,SUMINISTROS where PROVEEDORES.NIF=SUMINISTROS.NIF_PROVEEDOR AND SUMINISTROS.NIF_PROVEEDOR = c_nif;
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=true;
     
     OPEN cur_platos;
     FETCH cur_platos INTO c_codPla,c_platos;
     
     WHILE fin = false DO
     
           SELECT c_platos;
           OPEN cur_componentes;
           FETCH cur_componentes INTO c_nombres;
           
           WHILE fin = false DO
           
                 SELECT c_nombres;  
                 OPEN cur_proveedores;
                 FETCH cur_proveedores INTO c_nif,c_pnombres;
                 
                 WHILE fin = false DO 
       
                       SELECT c_pnombres;
                       FETCH cur_proveedores INTO c_nif,c_pnombres;
                       
                 END WHILE;
                 
                 
                 
                 SET fin = false;
                 FETCH cur_componentes INTO c_nombres;
                 CLOSE cur_proveedores;
                 
                 
           END WHILE;
           
           SET fin = false;
           CLOSE cur_componentes;
           FETCH cur_platos INTO c_codPla,c_platos;
           
     END WHILE;
     
     SET fin = false;
     CLOSE cur_platos;
     
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL plato();
```

Debe tener un orden el cual es el siguiente primero en nombre del plato luego sus ingredientes y luego los proveedores que proveen esos alimentos.

Por ejemplo debe salir para el primero `sopa de atletas de tiburón`, `atletas de tiburón`, `almendras` y entonces me tiene que devolver el proveedor o proveedores que suministran ese o esos alimentos.

**Para ejecutar mi código :** [<kbd>EJECUTAR CURSOR</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/186)

Comment: Cuando algo falle, revisa la consulta del cursor que está fallando. En `cur_proveedores` estarías ejecutando la siguiente consulta: `SELECT PROVEEDORES.nif,PROVEEDORES.nombre 
     FROM PROVEEDORES,SUMINISTROS where SUMINISTROS.NIF_PROVEEDOR = c_nif;` ahora bien, ¿de dónde sacas el valor de `c_nif`?

Comment: @A.Cedano solucionado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.*** El error estaba en el tercer cursor ya que ponía mas tablas de las que estaban implicada y lo solucione de la siguiente manera `select PROVEEDORES.nif,PROVEEDORES.nombre from PROVEEDORES,SUMINISTROS where SUMINISTROS.NIF_PROVEEDOR=PROVEEDORES.nif and SUMINISTROS.NOMBRE_ALIMENTO=c_nombres;`

***2.*** Los ***fetch*** de lectura estaban mal colocado por lo que no lo leía la entrada de datos.

***3.*** El `SET fin = false` también estaba mal posicionado ya que yo primero puse el ***fetch*** y luego el ***SET*** y es al reves.

## Solución :

```
USE COCINA;

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS plato $$
CREATE PROCEDURE plato()
BEGIN
    DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
    DECLARE c_platos VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE c_codPla INT;
    DECLARE c_nombres VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE c_nif VARCHAR(9);
    DECLARE c_pnombres VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE cur_platos CURSOR FOR SELECT CODIGO,NOMBRE FROM PLATOS;
    DECLARE cur_componentes CURSOR FOR SELECT COMPOSICION.NOMBRE FROM COMPOSICION where COMPOSICION.COD_PLATO=c_codPla;
    DECLARE cur_proveedores CURSOR FOR  select PROVEEDORES.nif,PROVEEDORES.nombre from PROVEEDORES,SUMINISTROS where 
    SUMINISTROS.NIF_PROVEEDOR=PROVEEDORES.nif and SUMINISTROS.NOMBRE_ALIMENTO=c_nombres;  
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin = true;

    OPEN cur_platos;
    FETCH cur_platos INTO c_codPla,c_platos;

    WHILE fin = false DO

        SELECT c_platos;
        OPEN cur_componentes;
        FETCH cur_componentes INTO c_nombres;

        WHILE fin = false DO

            SELECT c_nombres;
            OPEN cur_proveedores;
            FETCH cur_proveedores INTO c_nif,c_pnombres;

            WHILE fin = false DO

                SELECT c_pnombres;
                FETCH cur_proveedores INTO c_nif,c_pnombres;

            END WHILE;
                        
            SET fin = false;
            FETCH cur_proveedores INTO c_nif,c_pnombres;
            CLOSE cur_proveedores;
            FETCH cur_componentes INTO c_nombres;

        END WHILE;

        SET fin = false;
        CLOSE cur_componentes;
        FETCH cur_platos INTO c_codPla, c_platos;

    END WHILE;

    SET fin = false;
    CLOSE cur_platos;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Luego lo ejecuto con el ***CALL*** y listo.

```
CALL plato();
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/217)

Comment: Recuerda indicar una breve explicación de qué cambió, por qué esta versión del código resuelve el problema, etc. COsas que ayuden a que otros puedan usar tu solución para resolver su propia pregunta :)

Comment: @Alfabravo lo acabo de comentar mis fallos

Answer (score 0):

Cuando algo falle, revisa la consulta del cursor que está fallando. En `cur_proveedores` estarías ejecutando la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
    PROVEEDORES.nif,
PROVEEDORES.nombre 
FROM PROVEEDORES,SUMINISTROS 
where SUMINISTROS.NIF_PROVEEDOR = c_nif;
```

Ahora bien, ¿de dónde sacas el valor de `c_nif` para usarlo en ese consulta? `c_nif` es tu variable declarada. Dado que intentas hacer un `JOIN` ente `PROVEEDORES` y `SUMINISTROS` lo lógico es que uses la columna relativa en la tabla `PROVEEDORES`, que es `nif`.

Modificando esa parte, el código debería funcionar:

```
 DECLARE cur_proveedores CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT 
         PROVEEDORES.nif,
         PROVEEDORES.nombre 
     FROM PROVEEDORES,SUMINISTROS 
     WHERE 
         SUMINISTROS.NIF_PROVEEDOR = PROVEEDORES.nif;
```

Aquí te dejo una nueva versión del fiddle con esa parte corregida:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
# BORRAR BASES DE DATOS COCINA SI EXISTE
    
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS COCINA;
    
    # CREAR BASES DE DATOS COCINA SI NO EXISTE
    
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS COCINA;
    
    # USAR BASES DE DATOS DE COCINA
    
    USE COCINA;
    
    # CREAR TABLA PLATOS
    
    CREATE TABLE PLATOS(
        CODIGO INT(4) PRIMARY KEY,
        DIFICULTA VARCHAR(10),
        MENU_DIA BOOLEAN,
        NOMBRE VARCHAR(45),
        PRECIO FLOAT(5),
        RECETAS TEXT
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE PLATOS
    
    INSERT INTO PLATOS VALUES(1,'PINCHE',TRUE,'SOPA DE ALETA DE TIBURON',6.00,'Antes de comenzar a elaborar esta receta, debemos poner en remojo la aleta de tiburón, durante
    2 días, y las setas chinas, durante 1 día. Pasado ese tiempo, las limpiamos, las secamos y las
    troceamos.
    Ponemos a calentar el caldo. Cortamos la pechuga de pollo en tiras finas y la incorporamos al
    caldo, junto con el resto de ingredientes, menos la harina y las almendras. Dejamos cocer, a
    fuego lento, durante 1 hora.
    Pasado ese tiempo, diluimos la harina de maíz en un poco de agua fría y la añadimos a la sopa
    para que espese. Ponemos también almendras al gusto. Rectificamos de sal y servimos.
    Para hacer la sopa más consistente podemos añadir al final una clara de huevo batida.
    La sopa de aleta de tiburón es más valorada por su textura que por su valor nutritivo, que es
    escaso. Podemos destacar el aporte de proteínas que suma la carne y el caldo de pollo, pero
    posee menos vitaminas y minerales que una tradicional sopa de verduras, por ejemplo.
    El alto contenido en mercurio de la aleta de tiburón hace que este plato no esté indicado para
    mujeres embarazadas y niños.'),
                             (10,'COCINERO',FALSE,'CREMA DE HIGOS AL OPORTO',7.00,NULL),
                             (11,'CHEF',FALSE,'CORDERO LECHAL CON ESPECIAS AROMAT',14.00,'Lo primero que haremos será empezar con el aderezo del cordero. La noche antes de asar el
    cordero preparamos un majado de tomillo fresco, romero fresco, ajo y aceite hasta la mitad del
    mortero.
    Impregnamos el cordero con la mezcla anterior, lo tapamos con film y lo guardamos en la nevera
    hasta el día siguiente.
    Precalentamos el horno a una temperatura alta, unos 250o C, para que al meter el cordero no
    tenga que cocinarse partiendo de un entorno frío.
    Cuando lo vayamos a asar, sacamos el cordero y salamos bien la carne por ambos lados.
    Colocamos la pierna en una cazuela de barro o cerámica, con la parte interior hacia arriba.
    Aunque os sobresalga un poco no os preocupéis ya que durante el horneado menguará de
    tamaño.
    Si no disponéis de este recipiente cabría la posibilidad de cocinarlo sobre la bandeja metálica del
    horno, aunque en este caso te recomiendo poner un poco de manteca en el agua. De este modo
    se evaporará más lentamente y no tendremos que reponerla.
    Bajamos la temperatura del horno a 160o C, necesitamos el horno con temperatura arriba y abajo.
    Vertemos el vaso de agua y el de vino blanco en la base de la cazuela o en la bandeja del horno
    y metemos todo en el horno.'),
                             (2,'COCINERO',FALSE,'POLLO CON SALSA DE ALMENDRAS',7.00,NULL),
                             (3,'COCINERO',FALSE,'PROFITEROLES CON CHOCOLATE',3.00,'En primer lugar precalentar el horno a 180 grados y preparar una bandeja de horno con papel
    pergamino o vegetal.
    Por otro lado, tamizamos la harina con ayuda de un colador o un tamizador. Por otro lado, en un
    cazo ponemos la mantequilla junto a la sal y 87 ml de agua, remover. Añadir la harina y formar
    una bola retirándola a un lado del cazo. A continuación, añadir los huevos uno a uno y batir hasta
    lograr una masa homogénea.
    En una manga pastelera o una bolsa de congelar tipo Zip, añadimos la masa y cortamos uno de
    los extremos. Hacemos 18 pastelitos del tamaño aproximado de una nuez. Hornear a 180 grados
    durante 35 minutos o hasta que los notes ligeramente dorados. Los dejamos enfriar.
    Preparando el ganache de chocolate
    
    Como buscamos un ganache suave para relleno la proporción es una parte de chocolate por dos
    de nata. Para coberturas donde buscamos una textua más firma sería proporción 1:1.
    Comenzamos troceandor el chocolate para picarlo podemos introducirlo en la picadora o poner
    trocitos en el mortero y darle ligeros golpecitos. Poner el chocolate en el microondas junto a una
    cucharadita de leche 30 segundos a máxima potencia. Trascurrido este tiempo si aún no está
    fundido del todo le damos 20 segundos a plena potencia y dejamos reposar un minuto. Luego
    vertemos ya el chocolate fundido donde tengamos la nata montada y mezclamos.
    En otra bolsa tipo Zip añadimos todo el ganache de chocolate, apretamos y hacemos un corte
    en el extremo. Cortar por la mitad los profiteroles y rellenarlos con el ganache. En la parte
    superior puedes añadir un poco más de ganache de chocolate azúcar glas o fideos de chocolate.'),
                             (4,'COCINERO',FALSE,'CREPES CON ROQUEFORT',4.00,NULL),
                             (5,'CHEF',FALSE,'POLLO TANDOHORI',12.00,NULL),
                             (6,'CHEF',FALSE,'PECHUGA DE PATO A SALSA GROSELLAS',15.00,NULL),
                             (7,'COCINERO',TRUE,'ESCALOPE DE TERNERA',7.50,NULL),
                             (8,'PINCHE',TRUE,'BOQUERONES EN VINAGRE',6.00,'Lo más importante en esta receta es la calidad de la materia prima que utilicéis. Los boquerones
    deben estar frescos. Boquerones tiesos, que ofrezca un poco de resistencia al doblarlo.
    La piel tiene que estar muy brillante y los ojos bien transparentes. Yo me suelo fiar al 100% de
    mi pescadera Isa, además es muy maja y me suele preguntar cómo los quiero y que receta voy
    a preparar con ellos.
    La parte de la limpieza es el trabajo más laborioso. Si no tenéis un pescadero/a majo debéis
    limpiarlos en casa, lo mejor es hacerlo en el fregadero debajo de un chorro de agua muy fría.
    De uno en uno, rompiendo la cabeza y arrastrando con la uña del pulgar las tripas y la espina,
    todo a la vez.
    Al hacer esto el boquerón queda abierto por la mitad, los dos lomos juntos en la cola, quitad
    separadlos y quitar la cola para que queden dos lomos separados y limpios.
    Lavamos los boquerones (tanto si ya vienen del pescadero limpios como si has hecho el trabajo
    en casa). Tienen que quedan bien limpios, sin restos de sangre.
    Ponemos encima de papel absorbente y secamos bien presionando por encima con más papel.
    Así lo tendremos listos para el marinado. Reservamos.
    El proceso de limpieza y el congelado posterior es fundamental para un buen resultado final.'),
                             (9,'COCINERO',TRUE,'AJO BLANCO CON UVA MOSCATEL',5.00,NULL);
    
    # CREAR TABLA COMPOSICION
    
    CREATE TABLE COMPOSICION(
        COD_PLATO INT(3),
        NOMBRE VARCHAR(30),
        CANTIDAD INT(4),
        PRIMARY KEY(COD_PLATO,NOMBRE)
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE COMPOSICION
    
    INSERT INTO COMPOSICION VALUES(1,'ALETA DE TIBURON',150),
                                  (1,'ALMENDRAS',30),
                                  (10,'HIGOS',100),
                                  (10,'OPORTO',25),
                                  (11,'ACEITE DE OLIVA',20),
                                  (11,'CLAVO',2),
                                  (11,'CORDERO',150),
                                  (11,'ROMERO',2),
                                  (2,'ALMENDRAS',30),
                                  (2,'POLLO',200),
                                  (3,'ALMENDRAS',15),
                                  (3,'BARRAS DE CHOCOLATE FONDANT',50),
                                  (3,'PROFITEROLES',100),
                                  (4,'CREPES',200),
                                  (4,'QUESO ROQUEFORT',100),
                                  (5,'CARDAMOMO',2),
                                  (5,'CURCUMA',2),
                                  (5,'POLLO',200),
                                  (6,'GROSELLA',20),
                                  (6,'PATO',100),
                                  (6,'VINAGRE',15),
                                  (7,'CLAVO',15),
                                  (7,'SOLOMILLO DE TERNERA',150),
                                  (8,'BOQUERONES',100),
                                  (8,'VINAGRE',15),
                                  (9,'ACEITE DE OLIVA',15),
                                  (9,'ALMENDRAS',120),
                                  (9,'UVA MOSCATEL',30);
    
    # CREAR TABLA PROVEEDORES
    
    CREATE TABLE PROVEEDORES(
        NIF VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
        NOMBRE VARCHAR(25),
        DIRECCION VARCHAR(35)
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE PROVEEDORES
    
    INSERT INTO PROVEEDORES VALUES('00188327R','KEMPO ICHI','DOMICILIOC/ALPARGATERITO, 2'),
                                  ('22777364G','TRANS PEPE','PZA. CONSTITUCION, 5'),
                                  ('23877346B','PRODUCTOS GALLO','AVD. BARCELONA, 23'),
                                  ('33562837H','AVICOLA','C/ FLAUTISTA DE HAMELIN, 3'),
                                  ('36636773G','GEMASA','BVD. LUIS PASTEUR, S/N'),
                                  ('78365636J','SALAZAR','C/ CARNICERITO, 56'),
                                  ('78373673T','FRUTAS ORTIZ','C/ ALFA, 45'),
                                  ('82664939H','BEBIDAS Y REFRESCOS PEPÍN','AVD. DR. ESCASSI, 15'),
                                  ('89623663T','SURFOTMAN','C/ NABUCO, S/N'),
                                  ('98236777M','PEDRO GÓMEZ','C/ CUARTELES, 12'),
                                  ('98623629C','AVIMA','C/ JACINTO VERDAGUER, 12'),
                                  ('99387467M','TINTORROS DE TRABUCO','PZA. GOYA, 12');
    
    # CREAR TABLA SUMINISTROS
    
    CREATE TABLE SUMINISTROS(
        NIF_PROVEEDOR VARCHAR(9),
        NOMBRE_ALIMENTO VARCHAR(35),
        PRIMARY KEY (NIF_PROVEEDOR,NOMBRE_ALIMENTO)
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE SUMINISTROS
    
    INSERT INTO SUMINISTROS VALUES('00188327R','ACEITE DE OLIVA'),
                                  ('00188327R','PATO'),
                                  ('22777364G','ALETA DE TIBURON'),
                                  ('22777364G','POLLO'),
                                  ('23877346B','ACEITE DE OLIVA'),
                                  ('23877346B','ALMENDRAS'),
                                  ('23877346B','BOQUERONES'),
                                  ('23877346B','PROFITEROLES'),
                                  ('33562837H','BARRAS DE CHOCOLATE FONDANT'),
                                  ('33562837H','CORDERO'),
                                  ('33562837H','QUESO ROQUEFORT'),
                                  ('36636773G','BOQUERONES'),
                                  ('36636773G','PATO'),
                                  ('36636773G','ROMERO'),
                                  ('78365636J','CARDAMOMO'),
                                  ('78365636J','SOLOMILLO DE TERNERA'),
                                  ('78373673T','CLAVO'),
                                  ('78373673T','GROSELLA'),
                                  ('78373673T','UVA MOSCATEL'),
                                  ('82664939H','CREPES'),
                                  ('89623663T','CORDERO'),
                                  ('89623663T','VINAGRE'),
                                  ('98236777M','CURCUMA'),
                                  ('98236777M','PATO'),
                                  ('98236777M','QUESO ROQUEFORT'),
                                  ('98236777M','VINAGRE'),
                                  ('98623629C','CURCUMA'),
                                  ('98623629C','HIGOS'),
                                  ('99387467M','OPORTO');
    
    # CREAR TABLA FACTURAS
    
    CREATE TABLE FACTURAS(
        NUMERO INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
        SUBTOTAL FLOAT(6),
        DESCUENTO FLOAT(5),
        IVA FLOAT(5),
        TOTAL FLOAT(6),
        PENDIENTE_PAGO BOOLEAN,
        NIF_PROVEEDOR VARCHAR(9),
        FECHA DATE
    );
    
    # INSERCION DE DATOS DE FACTURAS
    
    INSERT INTO FACTURAS VALUES(1,250.00,25.00,40.50,265.50,FALSE,'00188327R','2008-06-12'),
                               (2,350.00,50.00,54.00,354.00,FALSE,'00188327R','2009-07-13'),
                               (3,200.00,15.00,51.30,336.30,FALSE,'00188327R','2010-12-21'),
                               (4,500.00,60.00,79.20,519.20,TRUE,'00188327R','2011-03-01'),
                               (5,600.00,75.00,94.50,619.50,FALSE,'22777364G','2009-08-23'),
                               (6,400.00,20.00,68.40,448.40,TRUE,'22777364G','2010-12-12'),
                               (7,650.00,50.00,94.50,694.50,FALSE,'23877346B','2008-08-21'),
                               (8,700.00,80.00,111.60,731.60,FALSE,'23877346B','2009-09-16'),
                               (9,500.00,30.00,84.60,554.60,TRUE,'23877346B','2010-12-30'),
                               (10,670.00,70.00,94.50,619.50,FALSE,'33562837H','2009-12-30'),
                               (11,400.00,20.00,68.40,448.40,FALSE,'33562837H','2010-12-21'),
                               (12,800.00,100.00,126.00,826.00,TRUE,'33562837H','2011-02-12'),
                               (13,500.00,60.00,79.20,519.20,FALSE,'36636773G','2011-02-21'),
                               (14,820.00,20.00,144.00,944.00,FALSE,'78365636J','2010-09-18'),
                               (15,430.00,15.00,74.70,489.70,TRUE,'78365636J','2011-01-10'),
                               (16,690.00,90.00,94.50,694.50,FALSE,'78373673T','2008-07-16'),
                               (17,1020.00,70.00,171.00,1121.00,FALSE,'78373673T','2009-10-07'),
                               (18,980.00,40.00,169.20,1109.20,TRUE,'78373673T','2010-12-19'),
                               (19,700.00,80.00,111.60,731.60,FALSE,'82664939H','2010-12-12'),
                               (20,200.00,15.00,51.30,336.30,FALSE,'89623663T','2010-11-19'),
                               (21,400.00,20.00,68.40,448.40,FALSE,'89623663T','2011-02-27'),
                               (22,675.00,50.00,112.50,737.50,FALSE,'98236777M','2008-12-30'),
                               (23,1009.00,45.00,173.52,1137.52,FALSE,'98236777M','2009-12-30'),
                               (24,1500.00,200.00,234.00,1534.00,FALSE,'98236777M','2010-12-30'),
                               (25,1650.00,150.00,252.00,1750.00,TRUE,'98236777M','2011-01-03'),
                               (26,1650.00,150.00,252.00,1750.00,TRUE,'98236777M','2011-03-03'),
                               (27,250.00,25.00,40.50,265.50,FALSE,'98623629C','2010-11-22'),
                               (28,800.00,100.00,126.00,826.00,FALSE,'98623629C','2010-12-12'),
                               (29,700.00,80.00,111.60,731.60,FALSE,'99387467M','2010-12-30'),
                               (30,500.00,60.00,79.20,519.20,TRUE,'99387467M','2011-02-19');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
USE COCINA;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS plato ;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE plato()
BEGIN
     DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
     DECLARE c_platos VARCHAR(45);
     DECLARE c_codPla INT;
     DECLARE c_nombres VARCHAR(30);
     DECLARE c_nif VARCHAR(9);
     DECLARE c_pnombres VARCHAR(45);
     DECLARE cur_platos CURSOR FOR SELECT codigo,NOMBRE FROM PLATOS;
     DECLARE cur_componentes CURSOR FOR SELECT COMPOSICION.NOMBRE 
     FROM COMPOSICION,PLATOS where COMPOSICION.COD_PLATO=PLATOS.codigo 
     AND COMPOSICION.COD_PLATO=c_codPla;
     DECLARE cur_proveedores CURSOR FOR SELECT PROVEEDORES.nif,PROVEEDORES.nombre 
     FROM PROVEEDORES,SUMINISTROS where SUMINISTROS.NIF_PROVEEDOR = PROVEEDORES.nif;
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=true;
     
     OPEN cur_platos;
     FETCH cur_platos INTO c_codPla,c_platos;
     
     WHILE fin = false DO
     
           SELECT c_platos;
           OPEN cur_componentes;
           FETCH cur_componentes INTO c_nombres;
           
           WHILE fin = false DO
           
                 SELECT c_nombres;
                 
                 OPEN cur_proveedores;
                 
                 
                 WHILE fin = false DO 
                 
                       
                       SELECT c_pnombres;
                       FETCH cur_proveedores INTO c_nif,c_pnombres;
                       
                 END WHILE;
                
                 SET fin = false;
                 
                 CLOSE cur_proveedores;
                 FETCH cur_componentes INTO c_nombres;
                 
           END WHILE;
           SET fin = false;
           
           CLOSE cur_componentes;
           FETCH cur_platos INTO c_codPla,c_platos;
           
     END WHILE;
     SET fin = false;
     
     CLOSE cur_platos;
     
END ;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #4**

```
CALL plato();
```

| c_platos |
| --- |
| SOPA DE ALETA DE TIBURON |

| c_nombres |
| --- |
| ALETA DE TIBURON |

| c_pnombres |
| --- |
|  |

| c_pnombres |
| --- |
| KEMPO ICHI |

| c_pnombres |
| --- |
| KEMPO ICHI |

| c_pnombres |
| --- |
| TRANS PEPE |

| c_pnombres |
| --- |
| TRANS PEPE |

etc ...

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/184)

Comment: @JavierG.Raya edita la pregunta y explica lo que debe hacer tu código. El problema que planteabas inicialmente es que el valor de la columna era `null`.

Answer (score 0):

No termino de entender para qué usar tres cursores para resolver una simple consulta:

```
SELECT PLATO,NOMBRE_ALIMENTO,NOMBRE PROVEEDOR
  FROM (
    SELECT CODIGO COD_PLATO,
      NOMBRE PLATO
      FROM PLATOS  
  ) PLATOS JOIN (
    SELECT COD_PLATO,
      NOMBRE NOMBRE_ALIMENTO
      FROM COMPOSICION
  ) COMPOSICION USING(COD_PLATO)
  JOIN SUMINISTROS USING(NOMBRE_ALIMENTO)
  JOIN PROVEEDORES ON NIF=NIF_PROVEEDOR
  ORDER BY 1,2,3;

+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| PLATO                              | NOMBRE_ALIMENTO             | PROVEEDOR                  |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| AJO BLANCO CON UVA MOSCATEL        | ACEITE DE OLIVA             | KEMPO ICHI                 |
| AJO BLANCO CON UVA MOSCATEL        | ACEITE DE OLIVA             | PRODUCTOS GALLO            |
| AJO BLANCO CON UVA MOSCATEL        | ALMENDRAS                   | PRODUCTOS GALLO            |
| AJO BLANCO CON UVA MOSCATEL        | UVA MOSCATEL                | FRUTAS ORTIZ               |
| BOQUERONES EN VINAGRE              | BOQUERONES                  | GEMASA                     |
| BOQUERONES EN VINAGRE              | BOQUERONES                  | PRODUCTOS GALLO            |
...
```

Quiero entender que sea para practicarlos...

Comment: lo acabo de solucionar después de mucho intento @DavidJP

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! @JavierG.Raya

Comment: Muchas gracias @DavidJP